# Line numbers in errors JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I am looking for a way to include line numbers in the errors thrown, even if I have to do it manually - IE is terrible at this. Due to the sheer size of the code (about 180kb in advanced optimizations mode of the closure compiler), this would be really useful.

All potential errors are already well dealt with in try catch blocks, custom errors are implemented to throw good relevant messages etc. As I am slowly preparing for production, I want to know if any of you has done this error tracking before and how.

Comment: while IE sucks, MS has nice tools to debug JS in IE...gr? or nsb?

Comment: If you're using IE9, the `Web Development` tool has adequate JS debugging features.

Comment: Do you really need the line numbers? Or is the problem that you can't see the errors very well in the browser after closure compiler has merged/minified the javascript?

Comment: But the main purpose of the line numbers is you want to know where in the original source code the error happens, so you can debug in your dev environment or something, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this event to catch and log any JS error into a DB table

```
    //Catch all JQuery errors and log into the DB
    window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNo){
        //Do what you want with the error including line number 
    };
```